# How can i fit the mapview using Autoresizing in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, autoresizingmask

Now i am working on old project, client wants to add updating on that project.I newly added one viewController for showing `mapview`, but this mapview cannot fit on the screen like iphone6, etc.This application uses autoresizing for resizing different views.I set autoresize property for fit the mapview on screen i tried both programatically and xib.But its not working.How can i solve this issue?Please help me.

```
_mapView.autoresizesSubviews = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

or

[image: Autoresizing property for Mapview]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you tried to set frame of mapview programatically?. Also check if "Clip Subviews" and "Autoresize Subview" property of mapview is checked.

Comment: Clip Subviews" and "Autoresize Subview" are always checked . I added mapview directly to interface builder not programatically.

Comment: Try to set frame of mapview programatically.  [yourMapView setFrame:self.view.bounds];

Comment: Can you add screenshot for your UIViewController's scene which contains that mapview? I would like to see your view hierarchy.

Comment: @Mrunal,i edited my question with screenshot.

Comment: In code it should be: `_mapView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;` not the `autoresizesSubviews `. Also make sure,  `_mapView.autoresizesSubviews = YES`. Try this and let me know.

Comment: @Mrunal,I tried it but it is not working.

Comment: @Jasper Then it might be something else is updating MapView's frame. (Might be its superview)

Answer (score 0):

You should use Auto layout and set constraints.

Auto layout is the default now so if you still want to work with struts and springs you need to turn it off from the file inspector of the .xib:

[image: turning off auto layout from file inspector]

Answer (score 0):

Since using `autoLayout` is not an option as its an old project and migrating is a humongous task, I strongly suggest you to set the frame for the mapView via code.

For instance, according to the screenshot provided, the view has a search bar which stays at top and the mapView must occupy the entire free space that is left. You can code it as follows:

1. Create outlets for the `mapView` and `searchBar`
2. Set Frame of the `mapView` like

   ```
   CGSize superViewFrameSize = self.view.bounds.size;
   CGSize searchBarFrameSize = self.searchBar.bounds.size;
   CGRect mapviewFrame = CGRect mapviewFrame = CGRectMake(0, searchBarFrameSize.height, superViewFrameSize.width, superViewFrameSize.height - searchBarFrameSize.height);
   self.mapView.frame = mapviewFrame;
   ```

The code takes the size of the `superView` and `searchBar` and holds it in temporary variables. Then create a `CGRect` variable to hold the new frame of the `mapView`. Place the `mapView` below the `searchBar` by setting its origin as the height of the `searchBar`. Set width of `mapView` to be same as that of its `superView`. Set Height of `mapView` as the reduced height of the `searchBar` from its `superView`.

Hope this helps :)